# Why does the second line not appear?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The second line / row I'm trying to put the title of the video. but everything I put in it does not appear.

I already created another container and put the second line in it and it didn't work.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <iframe class="video" id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="1280" height="720"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D9--l0QRS50"
                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <span>TITULOO</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am creating a page a bit like youtube, that appears the video and the title below.

Comment: I think you need to close your `iframe`

Comment: Thanks!! <3 
all working!

Answer (score 3):

I would say the same as @indefinite. An Iframe tag is not selfclosing so it follows this syntax `<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" height="200" width="300"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

correct Your code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <iframe class="video" id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="1280" height="720"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/D9--l0QRS50"
                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <span>TITULOO</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```